# How to create an custom Mint USB using Cubic that actually boots?

Tags: bootable

On my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS desktop, I tried Ubuntu Customization Kit and it wouldn't let me get to the terminal to customize my ISO. So I switched to Cubic. Cubic seemed to work as it let me get to the terminal and it produced an ISO without errors. Then when I used Startup Disk Creator to create my USB from the iso, that seemed to work too. The USB was formatted and populated. Unfortunately, the resulting USB drive fails to boot.

I used Mint 18.1 64 bit (also tried Ubuntu 16.04.1 and 16.10) as my base ISO. And the commands I ran in the terminal from Cubic are as follows:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java;
add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/atom;
apt update;
apt install oracle-java9-installer atom python-pip python-wxgtk3.0 git keepassx libxss1 libappindicator1 libindicator7 -y;
apt install -f -y;
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb;
dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb;
rm google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb;
pip install --upgrade pip;
pip install setuptools;
pip install --user git+https://github.com/thetimelineproj/humblewx.git;
wget https://jenkins.rickardlindberg.me/job/timeline-linux-source/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/timeline-1.13.0-beta-5e499bb0d658-2017-01-08.zip;
unzip "timeline-1.13.0-beta-5e499bb0d658-2017-01-08.zip" -d /opt/;
rm "timeline-1.13.0-beta-5e499bb0d658-2017-01-08.zip"
```

When I tried to boot my laptop with the USB drive it just returns to the boot menu. When I try to boot the iso using QEMU it says there is nothing to boot.

According to this:
https://answers.launchpad.net/cubic/+question/387566

I need to:

> Need to install syslinux-utils and run in terminal $ sudo isohybrid /path/to/custom_iso.iso

But that didn't work for me. The only output I got was:

> isohybrid: Warning: more than 1024 cylinders: 2215 isohybrid: Not all
>   BIOSes will be able to boot this device

How do I fix this?

Comment: A USB should not be ISO, it needs to be same format as a hard disk. The firmware in PCs is pick about this. The generator for Debian (and therefore probably for Ubuntu), that makes bootable Debian ISOs, makes a hybrid that will also work for USB. This does not mean that all ISO images will work from USB.

Comment: What do you mean “wouldn't let me get to the terminal”?

Comment: When you click the option to customize the ISO in the terminal it just throws an error and returns to the previous screen. When I did a Google search it looked like everyone was having this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I just should have had more patience. Running

```
sudo isohybrid /path/to/custom_iso.iso
```

fixed it. It did show an error message but the iso was modified and now it boots! :-)

Comment: I was about to suggest that. You got a warning not an error. The warning is because to miss quote something that I read “some idiot bios writers, though that USBs above 1024 could not exist.”